# Consider a fair coin flip. What is the mutual information between the top side and the bottom side of the coin?

Tags: probability, information-theory, mutual-information

Mutual information between the top side and the bottom side of the coin?.

T is the top side, B is the bottom side.

$$I(T;B) = H(B) - H(B|T) = \log(2) = 1$$

the log base is 2.

I don't know why the answer is.

$H(B)=\frac12\log2? \quad H(B)=\log2?$

Because p(B)=p(T)=0.5

I think $H(B)=\frac12\log2$ and $H(B|T)=0$,
but the answer is $$I(T;B) = H(B) - H(B|T) = \log(2) = 1.$$

from the solutions-elements-of-information-theory-2nd-edition-complete

Comment: What is the definition of "mutual information"?

Comment: The definition of "mutual information is I(T;B) = H(B) - H(B|T).

Comment: What exactly is B, and how you calculate $H(B)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to check the definitions more carefully. These are very elementary calculations.

The probabilities are
$$P(T\text{ happens})=\frac12,P(B\text{ happens})=\frac12$$
$$P(T\text{ happens}|B\text{ happens})=P(B\text{ happens}|T\text{ happens})=0$$
The marginal entropy
$$H(B)=H(T)=-\sum p\log p\\=-0.5\log0.5-0.5\log0.5=\log2=1$$
The conditional entropies
$$H(T|B)=H(B|T)=0$$
since one and only one of $B$ and $T$ can happen, if you know about one of them, the other is also determined.
Therefore,
$$I(T;B) = H(T) - H(T|B) = 1$$
$$I(B;T) = H(B) - H(B|T) = 1$$
In fact, it is always true that $I(T;B)=I(B;T)$.

Comment: Why the marginal entropy is H(B)=−0.5log0.5−0.5log0.5 ?
why not the H(B) =−0.5log0.5?

Comment: Because $B$ has two states, either it happens or it doesn't happen, each with possibility 0.5. To calculate entropy, you have to consider every state and their probabilities.

Comment: I think H(B) = p(B happens)*log(p(B happens))
Why should I add the state that B doesn't happen?

Comment: Please check carefully the definition of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). It's calculated over all possible outcomes.

Comment: Thanks, I see. The B is the random variable.